# Find buffer address to create shell code

Tags: c, linux, stack, shellcode, stack-frame

In my program I am trying to modify the EIP to point to buffer base address which contains shell code

example: 
**0xbffff5f3** is an address on stack which points to
`code[80] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\"`

I create a pointer `ret` and using stack frame knowledge point it to the base address of buffer.

```
{
//Some more pointer arithmetic on ret
(*ret) = (int)code;
return ;
}
```

Modified eip to

```
eip            0xbffff5f3   0xbffff5f3
```

**This works perfectly well and my shell code executes. But the `ret` is hard coded with the buffer address.**

However, now I would want to my shell code to contain the buffers base address known in advance so that the EIP is will point to it once the buffer overflows.

How can I know the buffers base address in advance ?

[![The buffer itself contains the address of shellcode][1]][1]

**Edit: Refining my question:** 
Given a statically declared array code[80], how can I determine before hand the base address of this array on stack, so that I can insert this base address into my shell code and insert appropriate padding bytes and NOPS to make EIP point to shell code ?

I have seen many examples on the Internet, and all of them demonstrate using GDB and figuring out the buffer address at runtime, however If I have to programmatically derive the shell codes address of can this be achieved.

Comment: I don't think you can just cast a string to a pointer like that.

Comment: @swiley a string in C is just an array of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way. You need to employ target-specific tricks.
They include:

- In relatively static programs without address-space randomization (or if the module has been compiled without relocations and thus cannot be moved around), you can guess statically (example: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/problem-finding-return-address-for-shellcode).
- brute-force all possible values, counting on the fact that sooner or later, you'll hit (misses will be mere DoSes or might be as small as errors in the server log if it e.g. restarts the faulty part)
- corrupt other entities in the code rather than/in addition to the return address to make them serve your cause (examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-to-libc_attack , [corrupt `esp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583889/executing-shellcode-stored-in-environment-variable-using-buffer-overflow))
- [use an additional recon attack](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~herbertb/misc/bufferoverflow/) that makes the server send you a clue